# Findpeaks in Spectrum Matalb

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find peaks in spectrum but I need to extract only peak of base frequency and its harmonics, red rectangular. How to exclude anything before base frequency and only include base frequency and its 3 harmonics. I use this code but it does not help. Any idea?

```
pks = findpeaks(q);
findpeaks(q,'MinPeakDistance',99)
%findpeaks(q,'MinPeakHeight',0.0004)
xlim([0.1 500])
```

[image]

When using:

```
    Fs = 1000;
t = 0:0.001:1-0.001;    % 250-Hz sine wave modulated at 100 Hz
x = [1+cos(2*pi*100*t)].*cos(2*pi*250*t);
%envspectrum(x,Fs)
[ES,F]=envspectrum(x,Fs);

%%
findpeaks(ES,F)
% Now for only > 99 Hz (choose the freq you fancy)
idx = F >= 99; % greater than 99 Hz
findpeaks(ES(idx),F(idx)) % idx only select those F > 99
% Good? Keep the values of  amplitud and location (in frequencies) of the ES
[pks,loc] = findpeaks(ES(idx),F(idx));
% If you just want to have the first 5 peaks (or the n? you choose):
% Select only 3 first.
if length(pks) > 3  % Check you didnt get less peaks
    pks = pks(1:3);
    loc = loc(1:3);
end
% To plot the peaks in the envelope
plot(F(idx),ES(idx),loc,pks,'r*')
```

I get this:

[image]

And this as result:
[image]

Comment: I used the `findpeaks` function to plot all the Envelope Spectrum and it finds as frequencies with peaks the values 5, 75 and 172 Hz, which is wrong. It seem those values are equal to their neighbours. Why `findpeaks` finds them as 'peak values'? I don't know, something went wrong with the algorithm of the function. But it is a internal problem, it is not my code. As it is a problem of finding false peaks due to height, you can use a few arguments to avoid that (next)

Comment: You can try 3 options: use the input: `'MinPeakHeight'` to specify an absolute amplitude, `'MinPeakProminence '` for a relative amplitude or `'Threshold`' for a relative difference between its neighbours. Any of these 3 inputs should be enough to avoid the selection of the false peaks. Also I just read there's a specific input to say the number of peaks you want to find (`'NPeaks'`). I'll edit my answer then. For reference:  https://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#namevaluepairs

Comment: Also, it's clear the peaks or your ES are harmonics, so faster way: `findpeaks(ES,F,'MinPeakDistance',99, 'Npeak', 3)`. You were doing great. Sorry for the confusion but it is more difficult without an example from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, this work for specific generated signal, findpeaks(ES,F,'MinPeakDistance',99, 'Npeak', 3) but it does not work for any signal, I tried. I also can not use 'MinPeakHeight' 'MinPeakProminence ' or 'Threshold' because harmonic amplitude are only need and it could be surrounding peaks very close to harmonics.

Comment: The it is a much more specific problem and probably ahead of my scope. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED to adapt to new code with an example. We are applying on the envelope spectrum of a signal - `[ES,F] = envspectrum(sig,Fs);`-, so we know the signal and its frequency sampling (fs).

Still being the same process. You can just compute the values in `findpeaks()` for only those samples of your signal which are higher than 250 Hz. For that purpose, you define a logical array for the frequencies values you want to:

```
idx = F >= 250; % 250 Hz
```

And apply this logical index to the envelop spectrum of your signal and frequencies where you want to apply the function `findpeaks()`:

```
[pks,loc] = findpeaks(ES(idx),F(idx));
```

Example:

```
% Let's create a signal with fs = 2500 Hz
% This is just to create an example, don't worry about these lines
fs = 2500;
f0 = 25;
n = 8;
d = 0.02;
p = 0.12;
t = 0:1/fs:1-1/fs;
z = [1 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.05]*sin(2*pi*f0*[1 2 3 4 5]'.*t)/5;
% z: our signal
% t: time array of the signal (to plot)

% How does the signal look?
plot(t,z)

% Calculating the envelope signal and its spectrum
[ES,F]=envspectrum(z,fs);
% Plot the envelop if you want:
envspectrum(z,fs)

% ES: Envelope spectrum of the signal
% F: array of frequencies used for the spectrum (half our fs for Nyquist Theorem)

% Find the peaks of the envelope spectrum
   % Let's see how it is for all the envelope
findpeaks(ES,F)
   % Now for only > 250 Hz (choose the freq you fancy)
idx = F >= 250; % greater than 250 Hz
findpeaks(ES(idx),F(idx)) % idx only select those F > 250
   % Good? Keep the values of  amplitud and location (in frequencies) of the ES
      % Use 'NPeaks' input to tell function to select only 5 first peaks it can find.
[pks,loc] = findpeaks(ES(idx),F(idx), 'NPeaks', 5);

% To plot the peaks in the envelope
plot(F(idx),ES(idx),loc,pks,'r*')
% Note in this example the first peak (in 250 Hz) is not selected 
% because is not a local maximum when we narrow the envelope.

 % If the function select false peaks somehow, you can use
 %'MinPeakHeight' to specify an absolute amplitude, 'MinPeakProminence '
 %for a relative amplitude or 'Threshold' inputs for a better fit.
```

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/768537-use-findpeaks-on-specific-frequency-range

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#responsive_offcanvas

Comment: Sorry I can not make it work. I am using this code [ES,F] = envspectrum(sig,Fs); to get plot as above. How to get plot in Hz?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Let me edit the post to show you with that function. But, the way to use the function `findpeaks()` is the same. @user33834

Comment: Thanks. This should work but this part does not: if length(pks) > 5:  % Check you didnt get less peaks
    pks = pks[1:5];
    loc = loc[1:5];
end                           I got this error: if length(pks) > 5:  % Check you didnt get less peaks
                                                      ↑
Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing or extra characters.

Comment: Right, I got confuse with Python :) I haven't been writting for Matlab for a while. I'll change it. If this was what do you need check the answer as the green tick ;) @user33834

Comment: Thanks RobertoT, but sorry still does not work :(

Comment: The if-statement? That's strange. I can't do more without an example of your signal.  @user33834

Comment: Hello, I updated question including signal too. Hope so will help to understand better.